# How to decide for type of a property when creating an instance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm coding an online game in Unity. I'm also using a custom response shape for my HTTP responses, like below:

```
public class Response
{
    public string status;
    public List<string> messages;
    public List<T> data;
}
```

I want to decide on the type of "data" property when I receive an HTTP response. It can be any custom type. for example from type player:

```
public class Player
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public int gems;

    public Player(string id, string name, int gems)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.gems = gems;
    }
}
```

so the shape of response, in this case, will be like below:

```
public class Response
{
    public string status;
    public List<string> messages;
    public List<Player> data;
}
```

so I can parse and assign it like:

```
var player = JsonUtility.FromJson<Response>(response.ReadAsString()).data[0];
```

or for other use cases like:

```
var players = JsonUtility.FromJson<Response>(response.ReadAsString()).data;
```

but it will be different for each response around the code and I don't want to create so many classes for each.

Is this even possible? What are the options or/and the best way? How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if Unity likes that but you could try and make the `Response` class generic

```
[Serializable]
public class Response<T>
{
    public string status;
    public List<string> messages;
    public List<T> data;
}
```

and then use

```
var players = JsonUtility.FromJson<Response<Player>>(response.ReadAsString()).data;
var player1 = players[0];
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. Tnx. Just one more thing. Is the title of the question a proper title?

Comment: Also, Unity uses generics itself. for example the "GetComponent<T>()" method. Also, there is an official tutorial for generics in Unity and also generic classes in this link: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/generics#5c8923c5edbc2a113b6bc335. I don't know about limits but this one is working.

Comment: Yeah that's true .. in some cases though serialization of generics is limited e.g. `public UnityEvent<string> SomeEvent;` will not be visible in the Inspector but you would have to have an explicit implementation like `[Serializable] public class StringEvent : UnityEvent<string> { }` and then a field like `public StringEvent SomeeEvent;`. Therefore I wasn't quite sure if the JsonUtility understands custom generics ;)

Comment: Yeah... converting to/from JSON is another important thing here. My question is also contain converting from JSON using JsonUtility. Fortunately, it works too and I can access nested properties ( player properties in this case ) correctly. ( not tested UnityEvent )